# Software to manage statement of work language at task/paragraph level?

Tags: document-management

I work in an area where a large part of my time is spent building contracts for customers which cover software implementations.

The tasks we perform (which are written into the contract) are fairly standard and change only a little from one contract to the next. I would like to start managing these "paragraphs" (i.e. task language blocks) as individual entities, as it is often cumbersome to make sure everyone is working from the same language to start with.

Pushing the idea a bit further, it would be nice to be able to store the language blocks as formatted text, and have an interface which allows you to "click a checkbox" next to the given task blocks you want in a contract, and have it produce a word document with those tasks in the order desired.

In a way this then becomes a task library which can be used to heavily standardize our contract language.

Does such software exist out there? I know there are plenty that manage documents as a whole and revision control them, but I am looking for a level below that by managing paragraph items within the document which can then be amalgamated into a larger document which would then be handed off and managed by a standard contract approvals and signing process.

Thanks

Comment: Yes there is software for this. It can be extremely expensive though. What is you budget? Do you want gratis? Do you want open source? Also, what OS?

Comment: Is your question different from http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/combine-merge-separate-word-docs-into-larger-doc ? If yes, please make the difference more explicit, thanks :-)